# How to delete all files that start with some id

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
./data/
- 746816793183649862.json
- 746816793183649862055454.json
- 7468167931836498628454646.json
- 746816793183649862465464.json
- 5415567931836498624546.json
```

this is the basic file structure
I want to delete all files starting with the id `"746816793183649862"`
but not the other ones.

after the id come some random nr's but these need to be neglected

the remaining files should be

```
./data/
- 5415567931836498624546.json
```

it should be written in javascript and node.js
I know `fs.unlink()` exists but I can't really use it because I don't have the whole path and there are random numbers behind the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const directory = './data/';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require(“path”)

fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
       if(file.includes(“746816793183649862”)
             fs.unlinkSync( path.resolve(directory + file)
    });
});
```

`path.resolve()` should give you the absolute path for a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

async function deleteFileById(path, id) {
  const dir = await fs.promises.opendir(path);
  for await (const dirent of dir) {
    if (dirent.name.slice(0,id.length) === id){
      fs.unlinkSync(dirent.name);
    }
  }
}
deleteFileById('./','746816793183649862').catch(console.error);
```